# Intro class C# for loop issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on the following two problems for my intro level C# course. I've completed problem 3, but am having trouble with problem 4. The issue is that the total is not coming out correct, as it is not adding the first combo value entered and I'm not quite sure where I went wrong. I would appreciate any help you guys can provide with this. Please keep in mind this is an intro level course, so it needs to be simple for loops, if then statements, do while statements, etc. Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of customers: ");
        var numCust = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int lunchCombo = 0;
        decimal total = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
        lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for ( int i = 1; i < numCust; i++ )
            switch (lunchCombo)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
                    lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = total + 4.25M;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
                    lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = total + 5.75M;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
                    lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = total + 5.25M;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
                    lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = total + 3.75M;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                    break;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is {0}", total);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

3. A restaurant has 4 lunch combos for customers to choose:

   Combo 1: Fried chicken with slaw [price: 4.25]
   Combo 2: roast beef with mashed potato [price: 5.75]
   Combo 3: Fish and chips [price:5.25]
   Combo 4: soup and salad [price: 3.75]

   Write a program to ask which lunch combo the customer orders.  Use a switch statement to determine and display the amount of money the customer needs to pay.  Display “Invalid input” if the customer ordered something not on the menu.  Do not use any if…else statements.
4. Expand program 3 to calculate the total amount due from a group of customers.  The program first asks for the number of customers in the group.  Then it uses a loop to take the orders one by one.  If a customer orders something not on the menu, ignore that order and move on to the next customer.  Use the number of customer in the group to determine how many times the loop will execute.  Do not ask the user to enter a special value such as -1 to stop the loop.  Calculate and display the total amount of money the group needs to pay.

Comment: "it is not adding the first combo value entered" - probably because of this: `for ( int i = 1; i < numCust; i++ )`, you need to start at 0: `for ( int i = 0; i < numCust; i++ )`. In rare cases with 1-based indexing you might start at 1 but then go to "less *or* equal": `for ( int i = 1; i <= numCust; i++ )`. `0<num` iterates through `num` members, and `1<=num` also iterates through `num` members but starts at index 1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the customer what combo they want *outside* the switch statement. I'll just use psuedo-code, so I'm not directly doing your homework for you:

```
var total = 0;
var numCust = "How Many Customers?"

for (int i = 0; i < numCust; i++){
    var combo = "What Combo do you want?"
    switch (combo){
        case 1:
            total += 4.25;
            break;
        case 2:
            total += 5.25;
            break;
        case 4:
            total += 5.75;
            break;
    }
}

write("The total is: " + total);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I used your suggestions, but it's now only letting me enter the combo for 1 customer no matter the number of customers entered. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure your loop starts at 0 and make sure you're outputting the total outside the For loop

https://dotnetfiddle.net/QxNczG

Comment: I also notice that you don't have a curly brace to define your for loop in your original question. Check my .net fiddle to see the difference.

for {
   switch(x) { }
}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the existing ordering logic inside another loop on the number of customers you read at the beginning of your code. Here's the logic but you should write the code. I don't think it would help you learn anything if someone here would write the code for you.

```
loop (numCust) {
   read order number;
   loop (lunchCombo) {
      add to total;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one instance of each of the following two lines at the beginning of the for loop and before the switch statement:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter lunch combo purchased");
lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then you switch on which lunchCombo the user chose.

Plus, your for loop should either loop from i = 0 to i < numCust or from i = 1 to i <= numCust.  You're leaving off a customer with the way you have it.

Comment: This helped immensely. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to start your for loop at i = 0 instead of i = 1. Then inside the for loop, ask for the user's input for the lunch combo outside of the switch statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCust; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is this customer's order?");
    lunchCombo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (lunchCombo)
    {
        case 1:
            total = total + 4.25M;
            break;
        case 2:
            total = total + 5.75M;
            break;
        case 3:
            total = total + 5.25M;
            break;
        case 4:
            total = total + 3.75M;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Think about the effects of starting at 1 and where you're stopping the counter for i.**

That is to say you're counting starting at 1 to n-1, which means if you're looping through one time less than you intended to.  So, if numCustomers is 4, the loop results in:

```
i starts at | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
---------------------------------
i loop...   | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
```

So i'm not getting through enough times if I start at 1.  You'll need to make one of two changes.  Change i to start at 0, OR change the comparison to be <=.  Either will work.

And don't worry, this is a common error!

(Credit to Quantic for the comment answer!)